# Semaphore access patterns in C/C++ (Linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, semaphore

I am curious about the best way to store/use a semaphore.

Previously, I have always used semaphore stored in shared memory (because I am already using the shared memory anyway) as a `sem_t`, then used `sem_init()`, `sem_wait()`, `sem_timedwait()` and `sem_post()` to manipulate the semaphore.

However today I was reading through the `man` pages and started looking at `sem_get()`, `sem_ctl()`, etc... I thought this would be a good way to save the step of declaring shared memory just to get a semaphore. As I started coding this up, I realized I cannot find a way to get from `sem_get()` to `sem_t`.

If I utilize `shm_get()` am I only able to manually operate the semaphores with `sem_ctl()`? This requires tons of overhead that is masked away with `sem_wait()`, `sem_timedwait()` and `sem_post()`.

Is there a way to get a variable of type `sem_t` when you only have a variable of type `key_t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon deeper [reading](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/05/24/semaphores-in-linux.html?page=1), there are two types of semaphores that come standard with most Linux distributions; **System V** and **POSIX**. In brief, **System V** is a very do it yourself and perhaps "crude" tool, while **POSIX** is much more simple to use.

My problem was stemming from the fact I was previously unaware of the dichotomy. `sem_t` and it's friendly tools are come from the **POSIX** family, while `shmget()` and `shmctl()` come from the **System V** family - they are not compatible and there is no "out-of-the-box" go between.

The solution I was looking for was `sem_open()` and `sem_close()`. This allows a `char *name = "named_semaphore";` to identify the semaphore, which, in turn, returns a variable of `sem_t`.